# No segmentation fault with fork

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fork

This code makes a segmentation fault:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int *n; 
    *n = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("n: %d \n", *n);
    return 0;
}
```

while this works:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   int *n; 
   *n = atoi(argv[1]);
   pid_t pid = fork();
   if (pid == 0)
     return 0;
   else
     printf("n: %d \n", *n);
   return 0;
}
```

Why the second with the fork works? I know that after `int *n`, I should allocate space for an `int` with a `malloc()`, but using the `fork()` seems to do this automatically.

edit:
Now I understand Undefined behavior :)
But now I'm asking: what is the cause in this specific case?

Comment: Undefined behaviour is undefined; anything can happen and the result is legitimate.  Don't invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: "Somebody once told me that in basketball you can't hold the ball and run. I got a basketball and tried it and it worked just fine. He obviously didn't understand basketball. " - Roger Miller on undefined behavior

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does not work. (Or more precisely, you have undefined behavior)

1) The fork is just hiding the segfault, because you are not checking the exit code of the child process.

2) The allocation of memory is not automatic -- ever !

You are just writing to a random location, and you may just be "lucky" that in the second version that the random location is within your process space.

Comment: Or it does "work" (by the means of not crashing), but since it's UB, it can do anything..

Comment: @joumvaer92 -- that is just "random" luck -- you have corrupted something in your process space -- it is just "lucky" that it does not cause a crash.

Comment: @joumvaer92: you are unlucky (or lucky) that it produces the 'right' output.  But there's zero guarantee that you'll get the right answer because your code is invoking undefined behaviour.

Comment: I'll call that a bad luck, agree with @JonathanLeffler

Comment: i tried 100 times, I'm always lucky @JonathanLeffler

Comment: @joumvaer92 Rather, read about  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) once and try to understand. :-)

Comment: @joumvaer92: that shows your system is self-consistent — that's all.  There's no guarantee that you will get that behaviour on another system, or with a different compiler on your system, or a different version of your current compiler, or with different compiler options and your current compiler, or with different values in the process's environment, or …  It is 100% inconclusive that it worked 100 times in a row.  That's the (beauty?) dreadful danger of undefined behaviour; appearing to work is an OK undefined behaviour, but it isn't guaranteed to appear to work.

Comment: `The allocation of memory is not automatic -- ever !`...what about auto variables?

Comment: why the fork is hiding the seg fault?

Comment: I'm not so sure the `fork` is hiding a segfault.  Since both processes are writing to the console, if either (or both) segfault you should see an error message indicating that.

Comment: @joumvaer92 `fork()` here is irrelevant. Just ignore it.

Answer (score 4):

Both your code snippets invoke [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), courtesy,

1. using uninitialised and invalid memory `*n`
2. (maybe) using uninitialised and invalid memory `argv[1]` (if `argc` is not `>=2`)

Segmentation fault is **one of the many** side-effects of UB. UB case includes *working seamlessly* scenario, too.

> ***Why the second with the fork works?***

*It has nothing to do with presence (or absence) of `fork()` UB. TL;DR.*

> ***but using the fork() seems to do this automatically.***

Visuals can be deceptive. Don't put your money on UB.

Answer (score 3):

Because `n` is uninitialized and therefore pointing to an unknown memory address, you are invoking undefined behavior.  It might crash (as in the first example), or it might not (as in the second example).

In a situation like this something as simple as adding an unused variable can make a program crash that wasn't before, or vice versa.

Allocate memory for `n`, and you won't have that problem.

Edit:

The fact that running `./test 100` works when you run the second program, no matter how many times, is a matter of luck.  The fact that you added a call to `fork` (in this case) just so happened to rearrange the way memory is laid out so that it would work.  Later on you might decide to a a call to `printf` for extra debugging and all of a sudden it starts crashing again.

Adding the `fork` call didn't automatically allocate any space.

The only way to prevent a crash is to allocate memory for `n`, and to ensure that `argc` is at least 2 so that `argv[1]` points to someplace meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

it happens that you do not see the segfault as when running fork and returns 0, your code never runs `printf ("% d", *n)`

The segmentation foult occurs when you try to access a memory location that is not allowed, so the solution is to assign ana memory through malloc or calloc functions, otherwise still have the problem.
Try this:

```
 n=malloc(sizeof(int));
 *n=atoi(argv[1]);
```

Greetings

Comment: Shouldn't that be `*n=atoi(argv[1]);`?

Comment: Which means you want to assign the return value of `atoi` to what `n` points to, i.e. `*n`.  Otherwise you're overwriting the return value of `malloc`.

Comment: @dbush Did not understand what you meant, thanks for the correction